# tomcat 6 taking a long time to shutdown

Tags: tomcat

tomcat 6.32 on linux takes a long time to shutdown, why?  A webapp might be resource intensive, but still doesn't justify a 10 minute shut down time.  what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat will keep running while until all non-daemon threads die.

Do a `kill -3 pid` (on Unix) to see what threads are running.